# createStackNavigator with submenu

Tags: react-native

How can I create a submenu in createStackNavigator?

I created my navigation as below:

```
const MainStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Home: {
      screen: HomeScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        headerTitle: 'iRent'
      }
    },
    Company: {
      screen: CompanyDetails,
      navigationOptions: {
        headerTitle: 'Company Details'
      }
    },
    Snapshots: {
      screen: PropSnapshot,
      navigationOptions: {
        headerTitle: 'Property Snapshots'
      }
    }
}, {
  defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
      return {
        headerLeft: (
          <Ionicons
            style={{ paddingLeft: 10 }}
            onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}
            name="md-menu"
            size={30}
          />
        )
      };
    }
});

const AppDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  myApp: {
    screen: MainStackNavigator
  },
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerIcon: <FontAwesome name="home" size={20} />
    }
  },
  Company: {
    screen: CompanyDetails,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerIcon: <FontAwesome name="building-o" size={20} />
    }
  },
  Snapshots: {
    screen: PropSnapshot,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerIcon: <MaterialIcons name="data-usage" size={20} />
    }
  },
  LogOut: {
    screen: Login,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Log Out',
      drawerIcon: <Entypo name="log-out" size={20} />
    }
  }
});

const AppSwitchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  Login: { screen: Login },
  ForgotPassword: { screen: ForgotPassword },
  Main: { screen: AppDrawerNavigator }
});

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppSwitchNavigator);
```

It is working perfect, but how can I add submenus to the Company menu. I would like to have "Company Details", "Company Test" under the Company menu in the left menu bar. Is it possible to do using the createStackNavigator?

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far I understand, you need a dropdown menu which will contain your companies details when you click on company.
If you want this, then try to do with drawer navigation.
When you click on company a drawer will open between company and snapshot.
Rest navigate as you want.

Comment: Do you have an example of it?